# Java library to test CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Does anybody know Java library to test CLI?

I will have a XML description (in progress) of CLI for our product. I want to generate Javs wrapper to:
- pass valid/invalid arguments to command line
- parse stdout/stderr to find out predefined patterns

Thanks

Comment: could you explain what you mean by CLI ?

Comment: Command Line Interface (CLI)...

Comment: If you are referring to a library to help you with getting user input you can use 'java.lang.System.console();'. Check you http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79